# Python trino connection Close

Tags: python, trino

I use for connect:

```
conn_trino = trino.dbapi.connect(
        host='host',
        port=port,
        user='user'
    )
```

I cant see answer in google or stackoverflow (or i bad researcher =(

I am using

```
conn_trino.close()
```

But cant check status